# How to block SSH on an arbitrary non-standard port with iptables?

Tags: ssh, iptables

How to block SSH connection on an arbitrary non-standard port with iptables?

There's no way to distinguish SSH connection on non-standard port on 4th layer as both source port and destination port are arbitrary.

If I understand correctly one has to use binary matching to actually look at the header of the packet to detect a SSH handshake.

I've found [this](http://www.stearns.org/doc/iptables-u32.current.html) article dwelving into byte matching but it seems that it's somewhat dated as the commands the author uses are incomplete from the point of view of a rather new version of iptables.
It also seems that the author only inspects established traffic and therefore looks for different byte sequences.

Essentially the rule should looke like this:

```
iptables -t nat -a PREROUTING -p tcp -m --state NEW \! -f -m u32 --u32 "???" -j DROP
```

What values should be in the u32 section for the rule to match a new SSH connection?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by blocking non-standard ssh connections? A malicious actor can always tunnel his connection in some other protocol, everyone else knows who to call when noticing the port 22 block.

Comment: i used  an proxy on 443 and Tunnel me outside :p sofar i can always get out aslong ssl is enabled, sofar cirrectly @anx

Comment: There's an infected device on the network which is making a lot of SSH connections to various IP addresses on the Internet (supposedly trying to guess passwords on the other end). I'd like to identify this device. I could rewrite my question to "how to LOG SSH...", IMO it doesn't change the idea - to be able to detect SSH (or any other protocol for that matter) on L7 based on the bytes in the handshake packets with iptables.

Comment: Not what you asked, yet I recommend you use a stateful firewall with a short (icmp, ssh, https, dns, ntp) **whitelist**. Use the opportunity not only to find one malicious actor, but to detect ALL unauthorized/deprecated services in your network, possibly banning them permanently.